# How to use append or wrapinner div which has span tags in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add following html code into a div called by its id name `#nitspopupmenu` :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="pagesmenu">
       <span>
         <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Home
       </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to append the above html tags but that didn't worked then I tried wrapinner but confused with the documentation of wrapinner as it says we can insert `<span>` tags but I'm getting an error of illegal token.

My Jquery looks like:

```
var element = $("li").text();
$("#nitspopupmenu").wrapInner(function () {
   return "<div class='form-group'><div class = 'pagesmenu selected'><span><i class = 'fa fa-bars'></i>' + element + '</span></div></div>" 
 });
```

I'm getting the value of element in my console.log its working fine as desired.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.html()` to set new html or `.append()` to append the content.

Also make sure that you are concatenating element text correctly while concatenating it with string html:

```
 var element = $("li").text();
 $("#nitspopupmenu").html("<div class='form-group'><div class = 'pagesmenu selected'><span><i class = 'fa fa-bars'></i>" + element + "</span></div></div>" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'm getting < /span>< /div></ div> at the end...(

Comment: @NitishKumar:Can you reproduce the issue in fiddle.

Comment: Its very tough to, as I'm calling a popup where I'm displaying the elements of an ul tag. I'm using for loop to execute, while doing console.log I get all the elements but by adding the above answer I'm getting only the last item of ul and those three tags at the end of the element text.

Comment: @NitishKumar: sure can help with that. please reproduce issue  in fiddle with minimal code,

Comment: Is it because of the for loop? or any luck with the code?

Comment: Got it.. Everytime Html is overwriting I am bound to use append, anyways found the solution but accepted as the answer.

Comment: @NitishKumar: sorry. been to lunch. glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
var element = $("li").text();

$("#nitspopupmenu").hmtl('<div class="form-group"><div class="pagesmenu"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>'+element+'</span> </div></div>');
```